Using msmtp doesn't send system events from crontab
I am using msmtp and it works fine, except when it needs to send system events from crontab.
i.e. this crontab (root):
* * * * *   echo "A message from Cron"

fails with message:
sendmail: server message: 550 5.7.0 From address is not one of your addresses

It can correctly send mails TO root (it is in aliases) but not FROM root.
How can I fix this?

If it's cronie, then setting MAILTO MAILFROM in crontab might help. Check man 5 crontab…

I found the solution.
add these lines to /etc/msmtprc:
set_from_header on
allow_from_override off

